# Automated Product Export

Tags: magento2, export, automation

We use the product export data from the manual export process in a separate process that is done daily. I was wondering if it was possible to schedule this export somehow. I've done some searching on the web, but every extension that offers this ability is pretty pricey and include a lot of features we don't need. Is there a way to do this natively, or without downloading an extension?

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: You need to create cron job for that

Comment: @kamlesh thanks for the response, I was thinking that may be the case. Do you have any resources on how to do that? I'm fairly new to Magento and have never attempted that sort of thing.

Comment: No, I haven't any resources for that.